# ReSharper warnings for JavaScript naming convention on constructor functions

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions, resharper

In JavaScript, I like the naming convention of PascalCase for constructor functions and camelCase for other functions. It looks like ReSharper is configured for these settings. However, for code like this:

```
function Thing(a, b) {
    return {
        prop1: a,
        prop2: b
    };
}

var thing = new Thing(2, 6);
```

...I receive this warning:

> Name 'Thing' does not not match rule 'Local Function'. Suggested name is 'thing'.

It doesn't make a difference if I change `Thing` to this:

```
function Thing(a, b) {
    this.prop1 = a;
    this.prop2 = b;
}
```

I suspect that only "public" functions are considered constructors. Do any of you know how ReSharper differentiates between a "Local" and "Constructor" function? Even better, do you know how to override this behavior?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, this is a [bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-375244) in ReSharper. You can wait or fix it yourself. Or define it in global scope.

Btw, those functions do very, very different things. You definitely don't want to call the former a constructor.

Comment: Thanks for finding the bug report. I have a question though: how is the former function *not* a constructor? If a function returns a value when called with `new`, that returned value becomes the "this" for the created object. Plus, writing it this way, you get the same result whether you called it with `new` or without.

Comment: @Jacob because it doesn't construct objects of `Thing`, it returns objects of `Object`. In JS a constructor can return an instance of any "class", and returning object literal is a particular case where that feature allows one to negate the point of constructors and prototypes altogether.

Comment: @Jacob: just to elaborate, true "constructors" in js allow you to customize the .prototype property so that "new "-derived object instances can inherit properties. If you return a literal or fail to use new, there is no blank prototype to mess with.

Comment: @Jacob please hand out the bounty before the grace period ends, otherwise I only get 50 points :P The 100 points were already deducted from you so you will not lose anything.

Comment: Weird. Why wouldn't it just assign the bounty to the accepted answer?

Comment: @Jacob after the grace period it would, but only with 50% of the points

Comment: What's the point of that? If I accept the answer, obviously I'd want the bounty to go there.

Comment: @Jacob to discourage sniping I guess, often impossible questions have bounties and then just before expiration, someone can make an answer and have it upvoted by a friend or two. Then he will receive the bounty for nothing.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. The question asker still wouldn't have accepted the answer.

Comment: @Jacob the bounty is not related to accepted answer, if the bounty giver doesn't hand out the bounty, then it will automatically be handed to the one with most upvotes (since the question was impossible, there will only be one answer by the sniper) see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Comment: FYI, I just asked about this on meta, and found out that according to http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty, "If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts an answer during the bounty period, and the bounty expires without an explicit award – we assume the bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration." I hope this is still accurate because it would make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

if you want your constructor to be public, you can use this workaround:

```
(function(global){

    function kindOfPrivateFunction(thing){
       //Do something with thing
    }

    global.Thing = function(a, b) {
        this.prop1 = a;
        this.prop2 = b;

        knindOfPrivateFunction(this);
    };

    global.Thing.publicFunction = function() { };

})(this);
```

Or, if you don't want resharper to complains about "ThisInGlobalContext" :

```
(function(){

    function kindOfPrivateFunction(thing){
       //Do something with thing
    }

    this.Thing = function(a, b) {
        this.prop1 = a;
        this.prop2 = b;

        knindOfPrivateFunction(this);
    };

    this.Thing.publicFunction = function() { };

})();
```

**Edit**

Considering your class must be local, you can use a local object to "store" the local constructor. But that's really just a hack to shut off Resharper...

```
(function(){

    var local = {};

    function kindOfPrivateFunction(thing){
       //Do something with thing
    }

    local.Thing = function(a, b) {
        this.prop1 = a;
        this.prop2 = b;

        knindOfPrivateFunction(this);
    };

    local.Thing.prototype.publicFunction = function() { };

    var instance = new local.Thing(1, 2);

})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I don't want my constructor to be global. My question was about ReSharper complaining about the naming of constructors that *aren't* public.